# Create string with repeated fragment using lists

Tags: python, string, list, format, concatenation

I am looking for a elegant way to achieve the following:

I have a list (the size is dynamic, depends of the source file) of column names:

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

and a list of column size:

```
leng = [20, 30, 15]
```

and I want to achieve the string:

```
a = 'CREATE TABLE dbo.table
     (
      [col1] varchar(20)
     ,[col2] varchar(30)
     ,[col3] varchar(15)
     )'
```

I can generate this using:

```
a = 'CREATE TABLE dbo.table\n(\n('

for i in range(len(columns)):
    a = a + '[' + col[i] + '] varchar(' + str(leng[i]) + ')\n'

a = a + ')'

print(a)
```

I wonder if the part with column names can be replaced using format function or sth more elegant than just  "for" loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Be aware of SQL injection

Comment: Like this? `a = a + '[%s] varchar(%s)\n' %(columns[i], str(leng[i]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.join` and `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
leng = [20, 30, 15]

sampleStr = """CREATE TABLE dbo.table
     (
      {}
     )"""

print( sampleStr.format(",".join(["[{}] varchar({})".format(i, j) for i,j in zip(columns, leng)])) )
```

**Output:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table
     (
      [col1] varchar(20),[col2] varchar(30),[col3] varchar(15)
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to join columns and their length in parallel.

```
a = ('CREATE TABLE dbo.table (' 
     + ', '.join(['[{}] varchar({})'.format(col, n) 
                  for col, n in zip(columns, leng)])
     + ')'
     )

>>> a
'CREATE TABLE dbo.table ([col1] varchar(20), [col2] varchar(30), [col3] varchar(15))'
```